# Cant remove first TR with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For some strange reason i am unable to remove the first `<tr>` with this code:

```
$('tbody tr#2 .is_KW').remove();
```

This is my html table code:

```
<tbody>
<tr id="2" class="is_KW">
    <td class="KW" style="border-left: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid #F4F4F4;padding: 12px 14px;position: relative;text-align: left;">
        <img src="img/world/af.png" alt="" title="af" style="vertical-align:middle;"> sweden
    </td>
    <td class="RR" style="border-left: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid #F4F4F4;padding: 12px 14px;position: relative;text-align: left;">
        <strong>
        1000+ </strong>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your id is invalid anyway: it cannot start with a digit.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Not in HTML5. And it was supported by browsers before.

Comment: I like SO, everyday I learn something new :)

Comment: @dystroy Not Quite.  Yes in HTML5 id's can start or be entirely numeric but ID's that started numeric in the past had issues, particularly in Internet Explorer because it merged the ID and NAME namespaces with its auto-globals... but more specifically with its form collection access.  If you need to support any version of IE below 10 running in Standards Mode I would **HIGHLY** recommend against using ID's or NAME's that start with a digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
$('tbody tr#2.is_KW').remove();
```

Your selector, with the additional space, was targeting an element with class `is_KW` **inside** the `tr` element.

Note that when you have an ID, you should only use it :

```
$('#2').remove();
```

except of course if the class is meant as a condition for the removal and might be not present.

Comment: Sorry was a typo in the question, i have it like you wrote it

Comment: Then [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/4cH2S/). Or you have another problem. Please make a fiddle demonstrating it.

Comment: Don't forget that you may only have **one** element in a document with a given ID.